# EF6 и Postgres ошибка

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Сделал dll в которой  классы и датаконтекст

```
using rmclibrary.Model;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace rmclibrary
{
    public class RmcContext : DbContext
    {
        public RmcContext() : base("RmcContext")
        {

        }
 public DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
// ...and etc
    }

}
```

В классе Brand сделал тестовый метод Check

```
public class Brand
    {
        [Key]
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public string UID1C { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Prefix { get; set; }

    public void Check()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nachalo");
            using (var dc = new RmcContext())
            {

                var k = new Brand();
                k.Name = "trrr";
                k.Prefix = 4444;

                dc.Brands.Add(k);
                dc.SaveChanges();

            }

        }

    }
```

вот  файл app.config

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>    
    <providers>      
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />      
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
  <connectionStrings>    
    <add name="RmcContext" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=123456789;Database=rmctest;" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Миграции и апдейт базы данных проходят без проблем.

Эту  dll я добавляю в  пустой консольный проект и выполняю Check

```
using rmclibrary.Model;
using System;

    namespace DatabaseWorker
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("start");
                var z = new Brand();
                z.Check();            
            }
        }
    }
```

Выполнение  залипает и  выдает ошибку,через пару минут, на строчке `dc.Brands.Add(k);`
Ошибка:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "При установлении соединения с SQL Server произошла ошибка, связанная с сетью или с определенным экземпляром. Сервер не найден или недоступен. Убедитесь, что имя экземпляра указано правильно и что на SQL Server разрешены удаленные соединения. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Ошибка при обнаружении указанного сервера или экземпляра)"

Comment: По ошибке понятно, что происходит попытка соединения с SqlServer, вместо PostgreSQL. Почему-то класс контекста из dll не видит настройки в конфиге.

Comment: совершенно справедливо, именно такая  мысль и меня  посещает,